# c# win app forms detect the number of faces on image and prompt error message if there is more than 1 face

Tags: c#, winforms, face-detection

I am currently doing an ID pic uploading system using C# Windows App Forms and I would like to allow the user to upload an image and the image must only contain 1 front face.  To prevent user from uploading more than 1 face, I would like to prompt them an error message once the system detects more than one face in an image but I am not sure how to go about it. I used takuya takeuchi's dlibdotnet library.

Here is my current code.

```
namespace DetectTrial


{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        #region Fields
        private readonly BackgroundWorker _BackgroundWorker;
        #endregion

        #region Constructors
        public Form1()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this._BackgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            this._BackgroundWorker.DoWork += this.BackgroundWorkerOnDoWork;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Methods
        #region Event Handlers

        private void BackgroundWorkerOnDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs doWorkEventArgs)
        {
            var path = doWorkEventArgs.Argument as string;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path) || !File.Exists(path))
                return;

            using (var faceDetector = Dlib.GetFrontalFaceDetector())
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path)))
            using (var bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms))
            {
                using (var image = bitmap.ToArray2D<RgbPixel>())
                {
                    var dets = faceDetector.Operator(image);
                    foreach (var g in dets)
                        Dlib.DrawRectangle(image, g, new RgbPixel { Green = 255 }, thickness: 10);
                    var result = image.ToBitmap();
                    this.pictureBox1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        this.pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose();
                        this.pictureBox1.Image = result;
                    }));

                }

            }

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var opnfd = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                opnfd.Filter = "Image Files (*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;)|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png";
                if (opnfd.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    this._BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(opnfd.FileName);
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion
        #endregion
    }
}
```

I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: You've told us that you're using WinForms (unrelated to your question because you're not stuck on UI code), but you haven't actually told us what library you're using for facial detection. Any answer would involve code from this mystery library.

Comment: im using dlibdotnet library. im new to coding so i dont know how to go about it.

Comment: [This one?](https://github.com/takuya-takeuchi/DlibDotNet)

Comment: yes. my problem is that it detects multiple faces. what I need is to detect only one face and prompt an error message when more than one face is detected because its an ID pic uploading system

Comment: Is `dets` a collection of the detected faces?

Comment: yes. I think thats where the problem is? I don't know how to go about it but I have a hunch that maybe I need to use if-else statements? I just need someone to show me how to do it in code since I'm new at this

Comment: Yeah, you probably want something like `if (dets.Count() > 1) { error } else { drawingCode }`.

Comment: is it okay if u show me how to incorporate it in my existing code? do I need to remove foreach? sorry I'm still learning all of this. would appreciate it so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the library you're using, but if `dets` is a collection of detected face rectangles, you can probably use something like this:

```
var dets = faceDetector.Operator(image);
if (dets.Count() > 1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Too many faces! Why are there so many faces? I can't look. Please make it stop.");
    return;
}
else
{
    var g = dets.First();
    Dlib.DrawRectangle(image, g, new RgbPixel { Green = 255 }, thickness: 10);
    var result = image.ToBitmap();
    this.pictureBox1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        this.pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose();
        this.pictureBox1.Image = result;
    }));
}
```

Note that `Count()` and `First()` are extension methods from `System.Linq` so you'll need to make sure there's a `using System.Linq;` directive at the top of your code file.

Also, the `Invoke` code is probably better moved to the BackgroundWorker's [`OnRunWorkerCompleted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.onrunworkercompleted?view=net-5.0) event (where the cross-thread invoke will no longer be needed) and you can access the PictureBox directly.

Comment: It works. You're great! Thank you so much, John! x